# Homotopic Equivalence of the set of all continous maps from $X$ to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

If we have the set of all continuous maps from $X$ to $\Bbb R^n$ denoted by $C(X,\Bbb R^n)$ and $\sim$ is the relation on this set, how could we prove that every two elements in $C(X,\Bbb R^n)$ is homotopic?

Comment: I think you have to use that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, i.e. the constant map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopy equivalent to the identity on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing down a contraction of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then you can compse any map $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with this contraction without worrying about $X$ at all.

Answer (score 2):

If $f,g: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is homotopic to $g$  by 
the homotopy $H: X \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $H(x,t)= (1-t)f(x) + tg(x)$.

Clearly $H(-,0)=f$, $H(-,1) = g$ and $H$ is continuous.

All we need is that the codomain is convex to be able to do this. The domain $X$ plays no rôle of importance.

Comment: @DatSci13 There is a path $t \to tx + (1-t)y$ between any two points $x$ and $y$.. You can use the $0$-function too: just use $H(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)$ instead and that's an extra argument that's not needed.

Comment: $S^1$ is path connected but not every two paths $[0,1]\to S^1$ are homotopic.

Comment: @positrón0802 they are with free endpoints, as here. This is not related to the homotopy group of $S^1$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right. Thanks for the clarification.